# Create table and insert rows based on multiple select statements in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

My situation is after login my website I wanted to show how many employees active, inactive & also for department wise, collage wise employees list of counts.

For that I created a procedure to create temporary table if it is not exist else drop table create temporary table, after that I wrote some SQL queries to get count of employees, department with conditions & then I'm inserting records to table.

Then I need the inserted rows. Now my problem is while executing procedure in SQL it executes but it's not creating & inserting any rows, I don't know why this happens. Please help me if any knows a solution to this problem.

My code:

```
alter proc SP_TEMPRECORDFORCOUNT
as
begin

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TEMPRECORDFORCOUNT'))
BEGIN
   drop table dbo.TEMPRECORDFORCOUNT
END

create table dbo.TEMPRECORDFORCOUNT(totalemployeecount int,activeemployeecount int,inactiveemployeecount int,deptwiseemployeecount int,activeemployeecount int)

declare @totalemployeecount int
declare @activeemployeecount int
declare @inactiveemployeecount int
declare @deptwiseemployeecount int
declare @activeemployeecount int

select @totalemployeecount =COUNT(*) from Employee
select @activeemployeecount =COUNT(*) from Employee where status=1
select @inactiveemployeecount =COUNT(*) from Employee where status=0
select @deptwiseemployeecount = count(*) from Department where e_id !=null 
select @activeemployeecount = count(*) from Department d inner join Employee e on d.e_id =e.e_id where status_id=1

insert into TEMPRECORDFORCOUNT
(
totalemployeecount 
,activeemployeecount 
,inactiveemployeecount 
,deptwiseemployeecount 
,activeemployeecount 
)
values
(
@totalemployeecount ,
@activeemployeecount ,
@inactiveemployeecount ,
@deptwiseemployeecount ,
@activeemployeecount ,
)
end

is it correct way thing i'm doing? if not please correct me.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQL Server 2008 R2 you have the option for table variables.

So your statement should be changed to the following:

```
DECLARE @TEMPRECORDFORCOUNT TABLE(totalemployeecount int,activeemployeecount int,inactiveemployeecount int,deptwiseemployeecount int,activeemployeecount int)

insert into @TEMPRECORDFORCOUNT
(
totalemployeecount 
,activeemployeecount 
,inactiveemployeecount 
,deptwiseemployeecount 
,activeemployeecount 
)
values
(
@totalemployeecount ,
@activeemployeecount ,
@inactiveemployeecount ,
@deptwiseemployeecount ,
@activeemployeecount ,
)

SELECT * FROM @TEMPRECORDFORCOUNT
;
```